# My android app gets stuck after pressing back button

Tags: android, eclipse

I was testing my app, now I have updated them from my last post. When I press the back button on the device the app gets stuck and a error comes up on the screen. I can't press the button on my emulator so i can't give the error.

I want also that when I click on a link without **http://** that it opens in the webview and when the url has **http://** , it opens in the browser.

Greetings Christophe

main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import be.my.app.ConnectionDetector;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*=== instellingen ===*/
        String url = "http://app.site.be?av=1"; //starturl

        /*=== verwerkingdsdata ===*/
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1); //koppeling layout aan id

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // javascript aan

        // flag for Internet connection status
        Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
     // Connection detector class
        ConnectionDetector cd;
     // creating connection detector class instance
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            view.loadUrl(url); // laad de url
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.niet_verbonden); //geen verbinding error weergeven
        }
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(myWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    myWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("http://")){ // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // Leave webview and use browser
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url); // Stay within this webview and load url
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you copy the error from the screen? Or, better yet, post the logcat output from the device. Also, the emulator usually has a back button (and you can use the `esc` key to emulate "Back" if it doesn't); does the problem simply not occur in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myWebView.canGoBack() == true){
```

here you are referencing `myWebView` wich is always null, due to not setting it,

and later you have

```
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

replace it with this

```
myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

this is the problem for sure

hope this helps

EDIT:
replace your code with this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import be.my.app.ConnectionDetector;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*=== instellingen ===*/
        String url = "http://app.site.be?av=1"; //starturl

        /*=== verwerkingdsdata ===*/
        myWebView= (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1); //koppeling layout aan id

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // javascript aan

        // flag for Internet connection status
        Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
     // Connection detector class
        ConnectionDetector cd;
     // creating connection detector class instance
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            myWebView.loadUrl(url); // laad de url
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.niet_verbonden); //geen verbinding error weergeven
        }
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(myWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    myWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("http://")){ // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // Leave webview and use browser
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url); // Stay within this webview and load url
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the back button works, but all the links will open in webview.

Comment: you should probably change this  if(url.contains("http://")) by this if(!url.contains("http://"))